# Entity framework enum - binding to WPF - show selected item

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I would like to ask for help with this task:

I have a Model Class with enum.

```
public enum ColorEnum { not set, black, white, red}
public ColorEnum Color {get; set }
```

Now I am creating WPF window - easy form for edit a car and I would like to bind the enum items to a comboBox. I am using a MVVM architecture. I am not sure, what to put into `EditCarViewModel` - I don't know how to reference the enum from the Entity Framework.

```
protected string color;
public string Color
{
    get
    {
        return color;
    }
    set
    {
        color = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Into the `EditCarWindow.xaml.cs` I added this code and in the ComboBox I can choose the options (colors) from the enum:

```
public EditCarUserControl(int idCar=0)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = new EditCarViewModel(idCar);
    ComboBoxColor.ItemsSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Car.ColorEnum));
}
```

But the problem is - I don't know how to let the color which is set in DB to be selected in the ComboBox. This does not work.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ComboBoxColor" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Margin="3" SelectedItem="{Binding Color, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"  />
```

I guess the problem is in the ViewModel - Of course I can't have the fuel as a string - but what should I do?

Any help would be appreciated.